# Condition to check field updates

Tags: visual-workflow

Values in the following pick list fields could be "Blank", "Required", "Completed"

F1_Review_Status

F2_Review_Status

F3_Review_Status

F4_Review_Status

**IF**

F1_Review_Status is updated from Required to Completed

F2_Review_Status    updated from Required to Completed

F3_Review_Status    was blank and is still blank i.e not updated

F4_Review_Status    was blank and is still blank i.e not updated

Then Update  Final_Review_Status = "Approved"

Basically IF all the fields that had value "Required" are updated to "Completed", but the fields that were blank are not updated (becuase there is no need for those to be updated)  THEN Update the    Final_Review_Status = "Approved"

The logic I have is obviously incorrect, because this means all the fields have to be updated from Required to Completed to  Update the  Final_Review_Status = "Approved"

[image]

**What I am thinking to make this work ?**

Any field's Record.OldValue = Required AND Record.NewValue = Completed
AND fields  value is blank  THEN Update the   Final_Review_Status = "Approved"

However, I don;t know how to build this condition in flow's decision element

Comment: often, you need to escape to a Formula resource called `isApprovable` and then you  have greater expressive power with the SFDC formula language to address the business logic

Comment: To build the formula, I would still have to check the values in the 4 picklists .  If out of 4 all were were Required, and now Comleted - set to true, IF 3 were required, and all 3 have Completed set to True, Two were Required and both were set to True , set to Complete, 1 was Required, and now completed, set to True. I can't figure out how i would put this in formula.

Comment: Give it a try (perhaps by building and testing incrementally). The flow debugger will be invaluable.

Comment: @cropredy I am thinking I could do this, All 4 picklists = Completed, Set Checkbox True OR (3 picklists = completed And 1 picklist = "" ) Set True, OR (2 picklists = completed And 2 picklist = "" ) Set True OR (1 picklists = completed And 3 picklist = "" ) Set True 
However the challenge is there will be so many permutations and combinations becuase  I can't use a function ANY3 , ANY2.